# how to substract two datetime.time values in django template,and how to format a duration as hour,minutes

Tags: python, django, filter

In a django app ,I am sending a list of `Entry` objects to the template.Each `Entry` object has a start, end times which are datetime.time values(from `TimeFields` on the form).While listing the Entry objects,I need to show the duration for each entry.Putting a duration field in model seemed to be reduntant since ,start and end times were already there

model

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=50)
    starttime=models.TimeField(null=True)
    endtime=models.TimeField(null=True)
...
```

template

```
{% for entry in object_list %}
<tr> 
  <td> {{entry.title}} </td>
  <td> {{entry.starttime}}</td>
  <td> {{entry.endtime}}</td>
  <td> want to show duration here </td>
{%endfor %}
```

`1.`Is there any filter which can take two datetime.time values and calculate the duration in seconds.
ie,

```
given
 t1=datetime.time(2,30,50) and
 t2=datetime.time(3,00,50)
should show
30 minutes
```

`2.`Also,is there a filter,that can show a duration in given number of minutes as hour,minutes if the minutes value is greater than 60

ie,

```
if duration is 50 minutes ==> 50 minutes
if duration is 150 minutes ==> 2 hours,30 minutes
```

**update**

```
def diff_in_time(start,end):
    startdelta=datetime.timedelta(hours=start.hour,minutes=start.minute,seconds=start.second)
    enddelta=datetime.timedelta(hours=end.hour,minutes=end.minute,seconds=end.second)
    return (enddelta-startdelta).seconds/60
```

when i tried with some sample time values ,it gave me the expected result

```
#start 11:35:00 pm
#end   00:05:00 am
start= datetime.time(23,35,00)
end = datetime.time(00,05,00)
print diff_in_time(start,end)

==> 30 minutes

#start 00:35:00 am
#end   01:35:00 am
start= datetime.time(00,35,00)
end = datetime.time(01,35,00)
print diff_in_time(start,end)

==>60 minutes
```

Comment: Such a shrewd and fine trick !!! Did you find that yourself ? or did you see it in a recipe from Alex Martelli ? or did you come to this trick by chance ? There's nothing to add. If the two times are within less than 24 hours one from the other , this solution is perfect. I see no possible particular case, it will always work. I hope you understand the reason of such a behavior : the internal representation of a timedelta instance is based on 3 attributes **days** , **seconds** and **microseconds**, among them only **days** may have a negative value. Then for a negative timedelta,

Comment: the values are adapted so that **seconds** and **microseconds** be positive , representing a lapse of time from an anterior day registered as negative. In a way, 24 hours are sustracted from the number of days, and 24 hours are added to the number of seconds: one compensates the other, but the number of seconds has its value augmented with 24, as is needed. Clever !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see where is the problem, apart in case the end-time would be later than 24 hours after the start-time.

Suppose that start-time is  9:00:00 and end-time is 13:00:00
If these times were taken on August 15, 9:00:00 and August 17, 13:00:00 , there would be no sense to try to obtain the time delta between them without knowing the days 15 and 17.

Hence there are two cases:

- either the start time and end time may be really separated by more than 24 hours , then as it has already been said, you must move to the use of datetime's objects
- either there is always less than 24 hours between the start-time and the end-time, then the problem is simple.

==========================

Let us examine the second case.

If
start-time 11:30:00
end-time.. 12:35:00
The end is evidently *1 hour 5 minutes* after the start

If
start-time 11:30:00
end-time.. 10:35:00
The end can't be before the start in the same morning, then the end is in fact in the morning of the next day after the day in which is the start, that is to say 24 hours later.

The same reasoning applies when the start is in the afternoon and the end time is apparently before the start time in the same day, in afternoon or morning: end time is in fact in the the next day, morning or afternoon, it depends but it's still 24 hours later.

#### 1)

So a little function, that need only the attributes of the times is sufficient to deduct the time difference:

```
def difft(start,end):
    a,b,c,d = start.hour, start.minute, start.second, start.microsecond
    w,x,y,z = end.hour, end.minute, end.second, end.microsecond
    delt = (w-a)*60 + (x-b) + (y-c)/60. + (z-d)/60000000
    return delt + 1440 if delt<0 else delt
```

The following code is only for a better display of the result:

from datetime import time

```
def difft(start,end):
    a,b,c,d = start.hour, start.minute, start.second, start.microsecond
    w,x,y,z = end.hour, end.minute, end.second, end.microsecond
    delt = (w-a)*60 + (x-b) + (y-c)/60. + (z-d)/60000000

    D = '%sh %smn %ss %sms - %sh %smn %ss %sms == '
    ft = '%s + 1440 = %s  (1440 = 24x60mn)'
    return D % (w,x,y,z,a,b,c,d) +( ft % (delt, delt+1440) if delt<0 else str(delt))


print difft(time(11,30,0),time(12,35,0))
print difft(time(11,30,0),time(10,35,0))
print
print difft(time(20,40,0),time(22,41,0))
print difft(time(20,40,0),time(18,41,0))
```

result

```
12h 35mn 0s 0ms - 11h 30mn 0s 0ms == 65.0
10h 35mn 0s 0ms - 11h 30mn 0s 0ms == -55.0 + 1440 = 1385.0  (1440 = 24x60mn)

22h 41mn 0s 0ms - 20h 40mn 0s 0ms == 121.0
18h 41mn 0s 0ms - 20h 40mn 0s 0ms == -119.0 + 1440 = 1321.0  (1440 = 24x60mn)
```

#### 2)

To obtain the durations in a more readable format:

```
def difft2(start,end):
    a,b,c,d = start.hour, start.minute, start.second, start.microsecond
    w,x,y,z = end.hour, end.minute, end.second, end.microsecond
    delt = (w-a)*60 + (x-b) + (y-c)/60. + (z-d)/60000000.
    if delt < 0:
        delt += 1440

    hh,rem = divmod(delt,60)
    hh = int(hh)
    mm = int(rem)
    rem = (rem - mm)*60
    ss = int(rem)
    ms = (rem - ss)*1000000
    ms = int(ms)

    SS = '%sh %smn %ss %sms - %sh %smn %ss %sms == %sh %smn %ss %sms'
    return SS % (w,x,y,z,a,b,c,d,hh,mm,ss,ms)



print difft2(time(11,30,0),time(12,35,45,478129))
print difft2(time(11,30,45,11),time(10,35,45,12))
print
print difft2(time(20,40,0),time(22,41,0))
print difft2(time(20,40,0),time(18,41,0))
```

result

```
12h 35mn 45s 478129ms - 11h 30mn 0s 0ms == 1h 5mn 45s 478128ms
10h 35mn 45s 12ms - 11h 30mn 45s 11ms == 23h 5mn 0s 1ms

22h 41mn 0s 0ms - 20h 40mn 0s 0ms == 2h 1mn 0s 0ms
18h 41mn 0s 0ms - 20h 40mn 0s 0ms == 22h 1mn 0s 0ms
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer..I tried to solve this, by creating 2 timedelta instances and substracting them .I have updated the question..I couldn't see if there were any cases where it would fail.(assuming that they are within 24 hours of each other)..but my knowledge of python and programming in general is minimal..so please tell me if there are any cases, where it may not work properly..

Answer (score 6):

You've got a problem. You can't -- and shouldn't be able to -- compare two times. Is 11pm before or after 1am? It depends whether or not they're on the same day.

You need to either store them as `datetime` or something else that represents a relatively absolute time, or you need to turn them into `datetime`s like this:

```
def todatetime(time):
    return datetime.datetime.today().replace(hour=time.hour, minute=time.minute, second=time.second, 
                                             microsecond=time.microsecond, tzinfo=time.tzinfo)

def timestodelta(starttime, endtime):
    return todatetime(endtime) - todatetime(starttime)
```

This will fail to give the expected answer if the two calls to `today` span midnight.

Then you should probably use this app for a [DurationField](http://django-durationfield.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) which stores a `timedelta` to store the result in the database for easy display.

Answer (score 4):

You can use builtin [timedelta](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#timeuntil) template tag.
In django template answer would be:

```
{{ t2|timeuntil:t1 }}
```

Answer (score 3):

Represent [duration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/models/#model-methods) as a property on your model:

```
from datetime import timedelta

@property
def duration(self):
    end = timedelta(self.endtime.hour, self.endtime.minute, self.endtime.second)
    start = timedelta(self.starttime.hour, self.starttime.minute, self.starttime.second)
    return end - start
```

Which returns a timedelta object. You can format it there as a string, or use a templatetag, etc.

Comment: He's using `datetime.time` you can't subtract them.

Answer (score 1):

1:

Probably not, but you could create your own tag, take a look at this code that does something similar:
[Timedelta template tag](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/210/)

2:

Again, i couldnt find anything like this. But it should be easy to code a custom tag to do it.
Something like:

```
def round_to_hours(minutes):
    return str(minutes/60) + ' hours and ' + str(minutes%60) + ' minutes'
register.filter(round_to_hours)
```

Of course, this is just a start code, There's much to improve.

As agf pointed out, you'll probably need a way to make timedelta objects.
You could try something like this (if you can assume both times are on the same day):

```
dummydate = datetime.date(1999,1,1)
delta = datetime.combine(dummydate, time1) - datetime.combine(dummydate, time2)
```

Comment: This still doesn't help as he can't get a timedelta.

Comment: @agf Not just with this. But you can always build a dummy datetime object and get the timedelta.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for Look at the time_delta_total_seconds. You might like to use the lib if you have complicated event scheduling requirements.

http://code.google.com/p/django-swingtime/source/browse/swingtime/utils.py

Answer (score 0):

I would probably just add a "duration" method to your Entry model.
It's easy, straight forward, and you can access it in the template like any other model field, {{ entry.duration }}.

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=50)
    starttime=models.TimeField(null=True)
    endtime=models.TimeField(null=True)

    def duration(self):
        # perform duration calculation here
        return duration_display
```

Comment: He's using `datetime.time` you can't subtract them.

Comment: Ok, it's upto him if he wants to change his models or attempt calculate the duration using using the existing TimeField.  In anycase, I suggest adding the "duration" method to this Entry model, and doing any necessary calculation there.  IMO this is more clear than adding a custom template tag.

Answer (score 0):

this could help too,
creating a python [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object.

```
from datetime import datetime
sub = datetime.strptime(str(start_time), "%H:%M:%S") - datetime.strptime(str(end_time), "%H:%M:%S")
# now `sub` is `datetime.timedelta`
```