# Python timedelta behaviour on subtraction

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

This question originated when I came upon ([another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065761/how-to-substract-two-datetime-time-values-in-django-template-and-how-to-format-a)) about Python's `datetime` and `timedelta` objects.

I followed the update by `jimgardener` and read the comments by `eyquem` ,and tried out some python code ..I am having a bad time understanding the  way things work here(due to my newbie to python status)..I thought it was  proper to ask a new question

```
import datetime
#for t1=23:30:00 PM
t1 = datetime.time(23,30,00)

#for t1=00:15:30 AM
t2 = datetime.time(0,15,30)

td1 = datetime.timedelta(hours=t1.hour,minutes = t1.minute,seconds=t1.second)

td2 = datetime.timedelta(hours=t2.hour,minutes = t2.minute,seconds=t2.second)

#substarcting timedeltas
tdiff = td2-td1
```

printing these variables yielded

```
td1 ==> datetime.timedelta(0, 84600)
td1.seconds ==> 84600

td2 ==> datetime.timedelta(0, 930)
td2.seconds ==> 930

tdiff ==> datetime.timedelta(-1, 2730)
```

When I looked at these results,I noticed that

```
td1.seconds (ie 84600) is equivalent to 
84600/60 ==> 1410 minutes
1410/60 ==> 23.5 hours
or in short,td1 represents the duration **from previous midnight** to 23:30 PM
```

now ,

```
td2.seconds (ie 930) is equivalent to
930/60 ==> 15.5 minutes or 15 minutes and 30 seconds
which means td2 represents the duration from **that midnight**
 to 00:15:30 AM
```

when tdiff is examined,I found that

```
tdiff ==> timedelta(-1,2730)
tdiff.seconds ==> 2730
tdiff.seconds/60 ==>45 minutes
```

this is the same as `duration between t1(23:30:00 PM) and t2(00:15:30 AM)` **assuming that t2 follows t1**

My question is,since td1 is the duration from **previous midnight**
to 23:30:00 PM  and td2 is the duration from **that midnight**
to 00:15:30 AM , how can their difference represent the duration between t2 and t1 ?

Can some python gurus explain

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `timedelta`s don't represent time from a midnight, just an **amount of time**.

If it took me **three hours** minus **four hours** to do something, it would take me **negative one hour**.

The difference between the two `timedelta`s is **negative one day** plus **45 minutes**.

This is the same as **negative 23 hours and 15 minutes**.

**15 minutes** minus **23 hours and 30 minutes** is **negative 23 hours and 15 minutes**.

Comment: I didn't understand how td(-1day+45mts) ie, timedelta(days=-1,seconds=2700) can be equal to td(-23hours+15mts) ie,timedelta(hours=-23,seconds=900)..it is a bit unclear

Comment: If I say "I ate breakfast 45 minutes into the future from one day ago", it's the same as saying "I ate breakfast 23 hours and 15 minutes ago".

Comment: Keep in mind that `timedelta`s can actually only be negative in the `days` field, and have no `hours` field, on purpose so that there is only one way to represent an amount of time with a timedelta.

Comment: ok..that means timedelta(days=-1,seconds=+2700) is equal to timedelta(hours=-23,seconds= -900)..thanks for the explanation..I missed the negative value of 900 seconds..