# how to convert a (possibly negative) Pandas TimeDelta in minutes (float)?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
df[['timestamp_utc','minute_ts','delta']].head()
Out[47]: 
            timestamp_utc           minute_ts                    delta
0 2015-05-21 14:06:33.414 2015-05-21 12:06:00 -1 days +21:59:26.586000
1 2015-05-21 14:06:33.414 2015-05-21 12:07:00 -1 days +22:00:26.586000
2 2015-05-21 14:06:33.414 2015-05-21 12:08:00 -1 days +22:01:26.586000
3 2015-05-21 14:06:33.414 2015-05-21 12:09:00 -1 days +22:02:26.586000
4 2015-05-21 14:06:33.414 2015-05-21 12:10:00 -1 days +22:03:26.586000
```

Where `df['delta']=df.minute_ts-df.timestamp_utc`

```
timestamp_utc     datetime64[ns]
minute_ts         datetime64[ns]
delta            timedelta64[ns]
```

Problem is, I would like to get the **number of (possibly negative) minutes** between `timestamp_utc` and `minutes_ts`, disregarding the seconds component.

So for the first row I would like to get `-120`. Indeed,`2015-05-21 12:06:00` is 120 minutes before `2015-05-21 14:06:33.414`.

What is the most pandaesque way to do it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['a'] = df['delta'] / np.timedelta64(1, 'm')
print (df)
            timestamp_utc           minute_ts                    delta  \
0 2015-05-21 14:06:33.414 2015-05-21 12:06:00 -1 days +21:59:26.586000   
1 2015-05-21 14:06:33.414 2015-05-21 12:07:00 -1 days +22:00:26.586000   
2 2015-05-21 14:06:33.414 2015-05-21 12:08:00 -1 days +22:01:26.586000   
3 2015-05-21 14:06:33.414 2015-05-21 12:09:00 -1 days +22:02:26.586000   
4 2015-05-21 14:06:33.414 2015-05-21 12:10:00 -1 days +22:03:26.586000   

          a  
0 -120.5569  
1 -119.5569  
2 -118.5569  
3 -117.5569  
4 -116.5569
```

And then convert `float` to `int`:

```
df['a'] = (df['delta'] / np.timedelta64(1, 'm')).astype(int)
print (df)
            timestamp_utc           minute_ts                    delta    a
0 2015-05-21 14:06:33.414 2015-05-21 12:06:00 -1 days +21:59:26.586000 -120
1 2015-05-21 14:06:33.414 2015-05-21 12:07:00 -1 days +22:00:26.586000 -119
2 2015-05-21 14:06:33.414 2015-05-21 12:08:00 -1 days +22:01:26.586000 -118
3 2015-05-21 14:06:33.414 2015-05-21 12:09:00 -1 days +22:02:26.586000 -117
4 2015-05-21 14:06:33.414 2015-05-21 12:10:00 -1 days +22:03:26.586000 -116
```

Comment: thanks jezrael but you see `a` still contains the seconds part. I just want -120, not -120.5569

Comment: hehehe you re too fast

Comment: If TimeStamp_1 > TimeStamp_2, then on doing TimeStamp_2 - TimeStamp_1 ... Can someone please explain, why id there a "-1" day in the Delta value ?

Comment: @le_llama - I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7091759) should help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Timedelta object](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html) in Pandas, and then use floor division in a list comprehension to calculate the minutes.  Note that the seconds property of `Timedelta` returns the number of seconds (>= 0 and less than 1 day), so that you must explicitly convert days to the corresponding minutes.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'minute_ts': [pd.Timestamp('2015-05-21 12:06:00'), 
                                 pd.Timestamp('2015-05-21 12:07:00'), 
                                 pd.Timestamp('2015-05-21 12:08:00'), 
                                 pd.Timestamp('2015-05-21 12:09:00'), 
                                 pd.Timestamp('2015-05-21 12:10:00')], 
                   'timestamp_utc': [pd.Timestamp('2015-05-21 14:06:33.414')] * 5})

df['minutes_neg'] = [td.days * 24 * 60 + td.seconds//60 
                 for td in [pd.Timedelta(delta) 
                            for delta in df.minute_ts - df.timestamp_utc]]

df['minutes_pos'] = [td.days * 24 * 60 + td.seconds//60 
                 for td in [pd.Timedelta(delta) 
                            for delta in df.timestamp_utc - df.minute_ts]]

>>> df
            minute_ts           timestamp_utc  minutes_neg  minutes_pos
0 2015-05-21 12:06:00 2015-05-21 14:06:33.414         -121          120
1 2015-05-21 12:07:00 2015-05-21 14:06:33.414         -120          119
2 2015-05-21 12:08:00 2015-05-21 14:06:33.414         -119          118
3 2015-05-21 12:09:00 2015-05-21 14:06:33.414         -118          117
4 2015-05-21 12:10:00 2015-05-21 14:06:33.414         -117          116
```

Note that the minutes are off by one because of floor division.  For example, 90 // 60 = 1, but -90 // 60 = -2.  You could add one to the result if it is negative, but there is the edge case of exactly one minute (measured at millisecond precision) would be off by one minute.

Comment: thanks alexander but does this solution work for both positive AND negative deltas?

Comment: thank you. otherwise one could get rid of the millisecond part from the timestamps directly dont you think?

Comment: No, but if your require absolute precision you could use `td.days * 24 * 60 + (np.floor(td.seconds) if td.seconds >= 0 else np.ceil(td.seconds)) // 60`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method [`total_seconds`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html). For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['2022-08-03 08:00', '2022-08-03 07:00'],
                   'B': ['2022-08-03 07:00', '2022-08-03 08:00']})
df = df.apply(pd.to_datetime)

(df['A'] - df['B']).dt.total_seconds() / 60
```

Output:

```
0    60.0
1   -60.0
dtype: float64
```